# Event Listener why does it get repeated for each additional character

Tags: javascript, button, events, event-handling, click

I am reading this example (first one on page):

https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-web-dev-v3/lessons/putting-it-all-together/events-and-listeners the first one with the click me and alert.

I dont understand why everytime a character is added in the alert box that a new event listener is created and if I add three "!!!"  , alert("Hey there!!!"); then the alert goes in extra 2 times, why is that? If I do this in w3 schools the same behavior does not occur

```
const button = document.querySelector(".event-button");
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  alert("Hey there!");
});
```

Comment: The code shown very much does not produce the behavior described.  It's not clear to me what you're asking.  If the problem is in some other code on some other website and not in the code you're showing us, please update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates what you're asking about.

Comment: @David increasing the number of `!` in the alert string causes the alert to show up multiple times, I was able to reproduce the behavior he is describing on the website

Comment: Yes what miss skooter said, I just dont get why adding text in the alert box adds an additional alert message for each character added

Comment: @xan: Well, presumably that other website has other code.  For example, if it has code which adds a new event listener each time text is modified in that input, then it'll add a new event listener with each keystroke.  The code shown has nothing to do with that functionality.

Comment: ok thanks david, I was not sure or if I was missing something I could not see